# Converting HTML to an Image

Tags: php, html, linux, image

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Convert URL to screenshot (script).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811674/convert-url-to-screenshot-script)
>   [PHP: How to capture browser window screen with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952570/php-how-to-capture-browser-window-screen-with-php)

I have a URL and I want to convert that webpage screenshot to an image. Please let me know if we can do this using php or some other tools that can be used with PHP/Linux.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Generate image from html with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702986/generate-image-from-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution, but you could convert the HTML page to a PDF, then use imagemagick to convert the pdf to a jpeg using this command `exec("convert sample.pdf sample.jpeg")`.   To convert HTML to pdf, see this question.

[Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: I would look at Gordon's comment, if that is what your trying to do, the question he is showing is a MUCH more ideal solution than this one.

Answer (score 0):

The [shutter screenshot tool](http://shutter-project.org/) is able to do that.

It's in the menu: `File` -> `New` -> `Web`

Can be used with Linux and PHP on the same system. See the [manpage for commandline options](http://shutter-project.org/wp-content/custom_html_files/shutter.pod.html) to be invoked from PHP.