# Generate image from html with php

Tags: php, html, image, gd

For some security reasons, I would like to generate an image based on Google Calendar embed iframe, to be able to show it on a website who don't allow iframes.

Is there any php library to create an image from html?

The script have to be executable on a linux server.

Comment: See this q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: Instead of downloading the Google Calendar HTML and somehow rendering an image of it, why don't you just put that HTML into your webpage (without an iframe, directly). Your script is a proxy.

Comment: Sparky: Thanks for that, I'll look this other question, didn't think to look for screenshot. Dan: I can only add html on the website, I don't have access to the php. I want more to generate an image trough a cron and link this image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The library [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) works perfectly.

I have created a page to embed the google calendar (the url can't be reach directly).

I generate a picture from this page and I link this image on my profile on the website.

Thanks heaps for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

functions from the GD library to output an image of the current screen

```
<?php
//All of your normal code would go here
//But before exiting, grab a snapshot
$image = imagegrabscreen();
imagejpeg($image,"my_screenshot.jpeg");
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Or use

[websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/free_services/) lets you capture screenshots of (almost) any web page. Allow your visitors to instantly visualize any web page before clicking. Increase site traffic, click-through rate and site stickiness.

Comment: imagegrabscreen needs a windows server to run and websnapr needs some javascript, I won't be able to use them