# How can i render an image from the string which contains html tags?

Tags: php, html, image, render

Hello everyone I have an obstacle, I hope someone can help me! I want to generate an image from the string which contains html tags: div, h1, img ... with .css styles applied.

Can it be done with php

I'd like to generate an image automaticaly and store in the folder in order to visualize it then on the page.
Is it possible to generate during the page load?

Example of the image: [image]

Maybe there are othe ways to build the image, I'd like to know.

Example: 
Suppose I have the following html tags:

```
<div class="mybox">
     <div class="mybox_title"> My Box </div>
     <div class="imgbox"><img src="myimage.png" alt="myimage"></div>    
</div>
```

I'd like to convert it into image.

Comment: This might help you: [How can I convert an HTML element to a canvas element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2732488/239241)

Comment: Can you expand on the question a bit?  I'm having trouble following what you're trying to do.  Use an example.

Comment: Why would you need to create an image from these html elements? Just interested...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php); [Converting HTML to an Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342178/converting-html-to-an-image); [Generate image from html with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702986/generate-image-from-html-with-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP library for converting html to image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963900/php-library-for-converting-html-to-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), which should fullfill your needs.

Comment: thank you. It works on the user side but i need to generate image on the server side.

Comment: Then you shouldn't include JavaScript and jQuery in your options of possible solutions, since JavaScript (and jQuery is nothing else than JavaScript) is (mainly) used on client side.